# create list of Boolean's list

Tags: python, loops, boolean, sequence, boolean-operations

I need to get the following: `([[True, True, False, False, False,     False],[ False, False,True, True, False, False],[False, False, False, False,True, True, ]])`

I wrote the following:

```
def create_bool():
    x_bool =[True, True, False, False,
                     False, False]
    arr_bool = []
    for i in range(3):
        arr_bool.append(x_bool)
        print(arr_bool)
        x_bool[:] = x_bool[-2:] + x_bool[0:-2]
        i+=1
    return arr_bool
```

but I got:`([[True, True, False, False, False, False], [True, True, False, False, False, False], [True, True, False, False, False, False]])`

Comment: Your rotation is off slightly: `x_bool = x_bool[-2:] + x_bool[:-2]`

Comment: Why not just arr_bool = [[True, True, False, False, False, False],[ False, False,True, True, False, False],[False, False, False, False,True, True, ]]?

Comment: This is a simple example (real case may contain up to 10000 of True/ False)

Answer (score 1):

you need to delete the index of x_bool set statement, and comment the i+=1. In a for loop the i automatically increases.

```
def create_bool():
    x_bool =[True, True, False, False, False, False]
    arr_bool = []
    for i in range(3):
        arr_bool.append(x_bool)
        x_bool = x_bool[-2:] + x_bool[0:-2]
        #i+=1
    
    print(arr_bool)
    
create_bool()
```

Output:

```
[[True, True, False, False, False, False], [False, False, True, True, False, False], [False, False, False, False, True, True]]
```